# SELECT DISTINCT - access

Tags: sql, ms-access

I am trying to create a query in Access that will return a count of members within a date range.

```
TransactionTable
TranID (pk)
ActivityID (fk)
MemberID (fk)
LocationID (fk)
TranDate
TranHours
```

This seems to work:

```
SELECT Count(*) AS UniqueMembers 
FROM   (SELECT DISTINCT transid 
        FROM   transactiontable) AS T;
```

But I start to become confused when I add parameter date range

```
SELECT Count(*) AS UniqueMembers 
FROM   (SELECT DISTINCT transid 
        FROM   transactiontable) AS T 
WHERE  ( transactiontable.trandate ) BETWEEN 
       [enter the start date:] AND [enter the end date:];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the query to have the WHERE Clause inside the sub select.

Something like

```
SELECT Count(*) AS UniqueMembers
FROM    (
            SELECT DISTINCT TransID 
            FROM TransactionTable 
            WHERE (TransactionTable.TranDate) Between [Enter the start date:] And [Enter the end date:]
        )  AS T;
```